# Firebase childrenCount into tableview label

Tags: swift, uitableview, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to get Firebase `childrenCount` as `string` into a `tableview` `label`. It prints all thous out but for some reason it doesn't put them into label.

What I am doing wrong, can you say?

I use `snapshot.childrenCount` to achieve this inside `cellForRowAtIndexPath`:

```
let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("Snuses").queryOrderedByChild("Brand").queryEqualToValue(brands[indexPath.row]) 
                        print(snapshot.childrenCount)
                        snusProductCountLabel.text = snapshot.childrenCount as? String

                    }
                }
            })
```

This is the output to console as I scroll:

```
7
3
8
3
26
5
5
1
8
3
10
```

Comment: Give the JSON tree containing this node `Snuses` ..

Comment: @Dravidian check my edit.

Answer (score 0):

I gotta be dumb. I solved it by casting the `UInt` to `Int` and then inside label `String(count)` like this:

```
let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("Snuses").queryOrderedByChild("Brand").queryEqualToValue(brands[indexPath.row])

        print(snapshot.childrenCount)
        var count: Int = Int(snapshot.childrenCount)
        snusProductCountLabel.text = String(count)

         }
     }
})
```

The only problem with this is that the label keeps changing while scrolling. But I try using `dispatch_a_sync`